# In PaperJS how to link onMouseUp event to origin of onMouseDown event when mouse has moved away from item

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, paperjs

In my PaperJS project I have a bunch of objects that have a circle Path associated with them. These paths each have mouse functions.

What I'd like to do is to create links between two circles when clicking on one, dragging the mouse, and releasing the mouse button on another circle.

For this I use the PaperJS `onMouseDown` and `onMouseUp` events, implemented like this inside the object:

```
function CircleObj() { // the object constructor
   this.circle = new Path(...);
   this.circle.onMouseDown = function(event) {
      //eventstuff
   }
}
```

where `this.circle` is the circle Path.

The problem is that when I release the mouse button it is no longer linked to the circle, and so the `onMouseUp` function doesn't execute until I click on the actual circle again. This therefore doesn't allow you to drag and drop over the other circle, since the 'drop' action doesn't register.

How can I have the `onMouseUp` event register and be linked to the circle where the `onMouseDown` event took place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep your mouse events tied to your constructor, I think it would be easiest to keep the initial point in a global variable. It's certainly cleaner than adding and removing a `Tool Event` to the view and checking to see if the hit object is a circle and not a line or other object.

```
var firstPoint = null;

function circleObj(p) {
    this.circle = new Path.Circle({
       center: p,
       radius: 20,
       fillColor: 'red'
    });
    this.circle.onMouseDown = function(event) {
            firstPoint = this.position;
    }
    this.circle.onMouseUp = function(event) {
        if (firstPoint !== null){
            var path = new Path.Line({
                from: firstPoint,
                to: this.position,
                strokeColor: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 40,
                strokeCap: 'butt'
            });
            path.sendToBack();
            firstPoint = null;
        }
    }
}

function onMouseDown(event){
    if (!event.item){
        circleObj(event.point);
        firstPoint = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you. Not ideal but looks like that'll have to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit more complicated but it avoids globals by encapsulating the problem in an object. Note `new Tool()` at the bottom of the sketch version - this is only necessary in sketch.paperjs.org in order to override the handler sketch installs.

```
function Circles() {
    this.group = new Group();
    this.circleNumber = 0;
    this.downItem = null;

    view.on('mousedown', function(e) {
        var hit = this.group.hitTest(e.point);
        // if we didn't hit this group add a circle
        if (!hit) {
            var circle = new Path.Circle({
                center: e.point,
                radius: 20,
                fillColor: 'red',
                name: 'circle' + this.circleNumber
            });
            this.group.addChild(circle);
            this.circleNumber++; 
            this.downItem = circle;
            return;
        }
        // we hit a circle
        this.downItem = hit.item;
    }.bind(this));

    view.on('mouseup', function(e) {
        var hit = this.group.hitTest(e.point);
        // if we hit a circle and it's not the same
        // as the downItem circle
        if (hit && hit.item !== this.downItem) {
            var line = new Path.Line({
                from: this.downItem.position,
                to: hit.item.position,
                strokeColor: 'black',
                strokeWidth: 20,
                strokeCap: 'butt'
            });
            line.sendToBack();
            this.downItem = null;
        }
    }.bind(this));
}

circles = new Circles();
```

Here's a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) if you'd like to play with it.